# Google app engine colons in query string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When a query string is sent to my server, if it contains colons, I can't seem to get the values correctly.

So for example if someone sent a link to me

```
.../?link=http://a-link.com
```

And I say

```
self.request.get('link')
```

It just doesn't seem to work.

However if I remove the colon then I get the value as expected.

What is the issue?

Comment: what do get the value of colon as ? I am guessing because of url encoding it may be `%3A`

Comment: In my browser I get them directly as colons.

Comment: What is returned from the `self.request.get('link')` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters in Url are reserved characters and have special meaning. To use them in Url parameters they must be properly [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

```
/?link=http://a-link.com
```

is not a proper URL. It should be:

```
/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fa-link.com
```

Comment: Seems weird. Keikoku's browser should do that by itself.